Anybody knows a deep link to prime video app?
I am working on this app where I need to redirect my users to Prime Video App, but I cannot find the right deep link anywhere. Can anybody help? And for other stream providers, like Max or netflix?
I tried different links from the web, and I expected they will send the user to the app, not to the web or the stores.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

For amazon: primevideo://, but if you  want the particular video: primevideo://watch/{ASIN}( {ASIN} is the Amazon Standard Identification Number for the specific content). I think you understand: Netflix paticular: nflx: //title/{id}. With Max you need to do the same: hbo://play/{content-id}.
And have you done something to exclude the errors when someone does not have an app?
And this question may also help you: Deep linking from another app isn't working for Amazon prime and disney+hotstar
